# Post on user facebook wall from web app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a way to leave the publication (not Share) on the wall of the user visiting the website.

I know about graph api (FB.api ('/me/feed', 'post', {message: 'test'}, ...)
But such a challenge requires the rights to publish at the user's authorization.

I want the right to publish on the user's wall requid not at authorization, but when user push the button "Send message to my Wall". And when user press the button (for posting), show window(Fb api confirm) appears to confirm an action

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are always hacks, but as one who has utilized hacks to make something work that shouldn't on facebook, I'm going to advise against it. When they catch you they will delete all accounts associated with that hack which may make some very unhappy customers. Doing what you are asking is forbidden by platform policy's.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi

Comment: It's weird. Instead of the right "to send anything, anytime" I beg, "send one time with fb confirm".  That is asking for less rights...

Comment: It may be asking for less, but think about it in terms of talking to a computer, You have to program every response. So they do not let you prefill items which would be the only way to accomplish the task you want.